# Given a string, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line

Tags: python, loops, join, append

> Given a string, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as
> space-separated strings on a single line.
>
> Example:
>
> `s = adbecf` => Print `abc def`

My approach:

```py
t = input()
p = len(t)

for i in range(p):
  s = t[i]
  n = len(s)
  even = []
  odd = []
  for j in range(n):
    if j % 2 == 0:
      even.append(s[j])
  for j in range(n):
    if j % 2 != 0:
      odd.append(s[j])
  first_join=''.join(even)
  second_join = ''.join(odd)
  print("{} {}".format(first_join,second_join)
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error " - in this case, please always provide the complete error traceback/message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use complex ways. here is a easy way to do it.

```
t = input()
p = len(t)
ans = "" # create empty string
for i in range(0,p,2):
    ans += t[i] # Add even characters
ans += " " # Add space.
for j in range(1,p,2):
    ans += t[j] # Add odd characters
print(ans)
```

Input: `adbecf`

Output: `abc def`